# Version control of xslx using gitlab

Tags: excel, git, version-control, gitlab

Query 1: How do we push xslx files into gitlab repo, are there any checks we need to do or any settings needs an update?  I am not able to add any files using git add and push them

Query 2 : when we push the files, does gitlab indicate any version control just the way it shows for source code?

In case this approach is not feasible, could some one suggest me an alternative way to achieve this using gitlab.

Comment: (1) Specifically, what happens when you try to commit the files? There is no technical reason that this shouldn't work. (2) What do you mean by "does gitlab indicate any version control just the way it shows for source code"?

Comment: (1) when i push the file, I get a message saying ``No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
Everything up-to-date``

Comment: (2) in case of any changes being made in the excel file, like a text is being replaced, or some content is changed, does gitlab show on how it displays for commits made on source code

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution yourself. Regarding question (2), GitLab will not show a "diff view" like you get with text files. Changes are still tracked, but it is very difficult to do things like diffing or merging on Excel files.

Comment: Thanks @Chris , but this has solved me a great problem of maintaining versions at least, I am very thankful to be on this community with helping people like you!

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the answer, The issue was not with respect to excel, it was coming up because of branch "master" not created.